# Returning kotlin data class using WebFlux and Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux

I am trying to return a `ServerResponse` with a data class, but I get this error.

> Failed to write HTTP message:
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No
>   converter found for return value of type: class
>   org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.DefaultEntityResponseBuilder$DefaultEntityResponse

I think this is because it isn't finding a public getter.

The top part of my response:

```
data class MyDataResponse(
        @SerializedName("metadata") val metadata:Metadata,
        @SerializedName("mydata") val my data: MyData?)
```

How it is used:

```
fun getMyData(): Mono<ServerResponse> = ServerResponse
        . ok().body(Mono.just(myService.getMyData()), MyDataResponse::class.java)
```

So, can I do this in Kotlin, or do I need to write my models in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see you are using `Gson` to deserialize your data. The default serializer in WebFlux is `Jackson`, which supports Kotlin (de)serialization.

As described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-kotlin.html), you need to add the [Jackson Kotlin Module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin) as a dependency, which will automatically be picked up and registered.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, it isn't ideal, but it does work.

```
fun getMyData(): MyDataResponse { 
return myService.getMyData()
}
```

This returns a JSON of the object, in my case.

I used the `data class` and it works.